# Basic Design for Full Page Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry if this has been asked before but I have been searching forever and still cannot come up with a basic design to achieve what I want for my layout (To confirm I do not want top and bottom white space)

I host a personal photography website where I post my amateur photography to friends and family and I would like to make it look a little better, In my head I would like each page to be none scrollable and I will make sure the content fits inside the space reasonably.

I'm not currently worried about limited space on mobile and tablet devices as when I have the basic structure I plan on making a mobile and a tablet page so that I can specify the design rather than a fluid site. (I may move to this at a later date)

So I would like to have the below example as my page layout

[Img Link](http://www.webdesignerforum.co.uk/uploads/monthly_11_2014/post-64302-0-07986600-1416312024.png)

I'm not sure how far off I am with my code I believe I have it almost there and I'm just missing the bit that allows my main div to be limited to the available space left on the screen between the end of the hr noshade and stop before the start of the footer div, this will allow such as a picture to be 100% hight of the div and the picture (or other object) will re resize depending on the size of the viewing area

I really appreciate any help and again apologies if this has been asked before, I'm trying my best not to put up a table formatted site as I know this is very ancient way of coding now

I have done some research and think I may need to use a jquery squirt the set the hight by the document/window but as I'm new to this I cannot find a good example

To sum up, I just want the main div to stretch from the bottom of the hr noshade line to the top of the footer.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
* html #outer {
  /* ie6 and under only*/
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: -20px auto 0;
  /*Change this to change height of footer must match .footer height number*/
  width: 70%;
}
.footer {
  height: 20px;
  /*Change this to change height of footer must match .wrapper margin -number*/
  background-color: #2C5463;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  color: #FCFCFC;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 151px;
}
.title {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: tangerine;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-variant: normal;
  color: #2C5463;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.main {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F80307;
}
hr {
  border-radius: 208px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #2C5463;
}
.menu {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FCFCFC;
  background-color: #2C5463;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  border-radius: 38px;
}
.menu2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FCFCFC;
  background-color: #2C5463;
  float: Right;
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  border-radius: 38px;
}
.menuwrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!--Start of CSS Link-->
  <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #e4e5e7;
    }
  </style>
  <!--End of CSS Link-->

  <!--Start of Fonts-->
  <script>
    var __adobewebfontsappname__ = "dreamweaver"
  </script>
  <script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/tangerine:n4,n7:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--End of Fonts-->

  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<!--Start of Webpage-->

<body>
  <!--Start of Page Wrapper (no main content above this line-->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!--Start of Main Content-->
    <div class="content">
      <!--Start of Page Content-->
      <!--Start of Title-->
      <div class="title">
        <p>Skc Photography</p>
      </div>
      <!--End of Title-->
      <!--Start of Member Login--
    <div class="login"><p>Member Login</p></div>
    <!--End of Member Login-->
      <!--Start of line-->
      <hr noshade>
      <!--Start of line-->
      <!--Start of Menu-->
      <div class="menuwrapper">
        <div class="menu">
          <p>Home</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <p>Galleries</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <p>Contact Me</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu2">
          <p>Member Login</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--End of Menu-->
      <!--Start of line-->
      <hr noshade>
      <!--Start of line-->
      <!--Start of Main Content-->
      <div class="main">This div needs to stretch to top of the Footer and not past it.
      </div>
      <!--End of Main Content-->
    </div>
    <!--End of Page Content-->
  </div>
  <!--End of Page Wrapper (no main content Below this line-->
  <!--Start of Footer-->
  <div class="footer">SKCPhotography - Copyright &copy; 2014</div>
  <!--End of Footer-->
</body>
<!--End of Webpage-->

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, what browser support are you going for? Do you need to support older versions of Internet Explorer, or are you ok with supporting IE10+ or even IE11+? With newer browsers, achieving a sticky footer layout is [much easier](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/) using flexbox. Otherwise, if you're aiming for maximum browser support, use [this site](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) as a guide.

Comment: I would like to make it as compatible as possible but also within reason. so i dont want to spend ages making backwards compatible as long as its compatible with up to date version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a `position: absolute` to the `.main` div, and add the parent `.wrapper` `position: relative`, and work you way from there, check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k7o9sth2/)

```
.main{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 126px;/*the height of the header menu, hr etc.*/
    right: 0;
}
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This looks perfect in the jsfiddle link, but when i add the code to my files it does not load properly

Comment: Share a screenshot, or something, it should work properly given the current css, and elements inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that layout easily if you set your main div with a height that calculates 100% minus the known height factors (your header, menu, and footer).

Here is a simple structured layout based on your request. You can probably replicate it in to your likings, I hope.

**NOTE: when viewing it, view it in full page because the page is too small for the main div to show**

```css
body, html { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

#container { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    text-align: center;
}

#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    background: orange;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: pink;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="menu">Menu</div>
  <div id="main">Main</div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change css. Than add one additional element in DOM and you're perfect.
So CSS you need to change is

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: -20px auto 0;
    width: 70%;
    position: relative;/*This is new*/
}    
.main {
    position: absolute;/*This is new*/
    /* float: left; */ REMOVE THIS
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;/*This is new*/
    background-color: #F80307;
 }
```

In div with class MAIN add another div that will be positioned relative.

```
.new_div{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: so you mean it should look like

<div class="main">
    <div class="new_main">This div needs to stretch to top of the Footer and not past it.
    </div></div>

and

.new_div{
    position: relative;
}

Comment: Yes, but you're adding "relative" container for safety :), actually there's no need for that element, but the parent div "absolute" can cause some weird things sometimes, the cases are unlimited. Have you tried above example?